# How to index existing documents in java with Solr

Tags: java, indexing, solr, lucene, nutch

I am trying to write an indexer for a search engine in Solr, using Java. I've been googling a lot. I found different approaches such as using a Core Container which adds the document and then the Solr server indexes all the data. another approach is to use Nutch, using Solr Indexer. 
I am new with Solr and do not know which code to use. BTW, I need to have the stored indexed document. I do not know where Solr is saving the indexed documents.
BTW, would it be better to use Nutch? 
I am so new with Solr, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest use Elasticsearch. Nutch is Crawler not indexer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Solr Data Import Handler.

Basically, in the core you create a data-config.xml with the datasource

```
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname" user="db_username" password="db_password"/>
```

and then you define how should Solr map the database information into Solr indexes something like:

```
<document name="products">
    <entity name="item" query="select * from item">
        <field column="ID" name="id" />
    </entity>
</document>
```

More reference [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Usage_with_RDBMS).

Also, if you need to use Java code, you can try with [spring-data-solr](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-solr/).

Hope this helps!